# Database server's Load reaches very high values while nothing seems to use CPU, what could be the reason?

Tags: mysql, database-performance

`top - 16:33:08 up 155 days,  6:05,  5 users,  load average: 27.93, 35.31, 31.34`
At this moment it only shows 27.0 but the behavior is like so:
While mysqld uses 0% cpu the load raises to high values (also the server is on 99.20 Idle)
Whenever a query arrives the server, mysqld process starts using some CPU while the load value decreases, what could cause such a wierd behavior?
During all this time, it seems like the server is on idle and nothing is written/read from the disks.

```
[root@mysqlsvr ~]# date ; sar
ד' אוג 14 16:29:17 IDT 2013
Linux 2.6.32-71.29.1.el6.x86_64 (mysqlsvr)  14/08/13    _x86_64_    (80 CPU)

15:30:01        CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
15:40:01        all      0.72      0.00      0.90      4.80      0.00     93.57
15:50:01        all      1.07      0.01      1.83      3.13      0.00     93.96
16:00:01        all      0.55      0.00      0.80      4.69      0.00     93.96
16:10:01        all      0.24      0.00      0.19      3.23      0.00     96.34
16:20:01        all      0.70      0.01      1.09      3.59      0.00     94.61
Average:        all      0.66      0.00      0.96      3.89      0.00     94.49
[root@mysqlsvr ~]# date ;iostat
ד' אוג 14 16:29:32 IDT 2013
Linux 2.6.32-71.29.1.el6.x86_64 (mysqlsvr)  14/08/13    _x86_64_    (80 CPU)

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.17    0.00    0.21    0.01    0.00   99.62

Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn
sda               0.89         1.12         7.26   15004502   97409836
sdb              16.10         0.96      1315.43   12815431 17644874178
dm-0              0.95         0.93         7.23   12433962   96936968
dm-1              0.00         0.00         0.01      15360      84016
dm-2            164.38         0.96      1315.43   12813185 17644874178
dm-3              0.01         0.02         0.03     333354     385384
fioa             88.60        29.26      1492.84  392514339 20024549216
drbd0            33.50        26.50       257.39  355470226 3452628864
drbd1            25.57         0.46       204.44    6197282 2742359000

[root@mysqlsvr ~]#
```

Comment: You're years behind on your updates. Go update the system.

Comment: But everything worked great until today, it all started when the firewall crashed and rebooted, since then it behaves like that.

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing problems with IO (look at %iowait). Most probably, you've got problems with disk performance/IOPS.

CPU resources cannot be completely used, because process is waiting data to arrive or be written.

You've got 80 CPU's, it's quite expected for load average to be that high in this case for this iowait.

Regarding reboot: if FS is fine - it's also expected with flushed disk cache and mysql memory.

How about memory usage? http://www.pixelbeat.org/scripts/ps_mem.py

free -m;cat /proc/mdstat